# Unusual Array Subscription in Gawk

Tags: arrays, subscription, gawk

I have tried looking for an explanation for a specific type of array subscription in gawk:

```
arr[tog = ! tog, 0] = i
```

But I can't seem to find the right searchterm to put into Google. The full code where I got that line can be found here: http://lawker.googlecode.com/svn/fridge/lib/awk/levenshtein.awk

Can anybody tell me what that does? Is it assigning a boolean flag `tog` to its inverse and using the result of the assignment as an array index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The stuff in the brackets is evaluated in arithmetic context (don't know where this is documented), so this inverts the boolean value of the variable tog, then sets `a[0]="i"` regardless of the value of tog:</strike>

```
$ tog=0
$ arr[tog = ! tog, 0]=i
$ echo $tog; echo "${!arr[@]}"
1
0
$ arr[tog = ! tog, 0]=i
$ echo $tog; echo "${!arr[@]}"
0
0
```

So, only array index 0 exists.

Whoa, that was completely wrong. I didn't see this was a gawk question.

gawk can't actually have multi-dimensional arrays, but it can fake them with comma-separated keys. The comma-separated elements are joined into a single string using the SUBSEP variable:

```
gawk '
    function do_toggle(i) { 
        arr[tog = ! tog, 0] = i 
        print "after toggling:"
        print tog
        for (idx in arr) print "arr["idx"]="arr[idx]
    }
    BEGIN {
        SUBSEP=":"
        tog=0
        do_toggle(5)
        do_toggle(10)
    }
'
```

```
after toggling:
1
arr[1:0]=5
after toggling:
0
arr[1:0]=5
arr[0:0]=10
```

Comment: @DaraJavaherian, please see my updated answer. I was answering your gawk question with bash code.